# How do I create the empty table data boxes with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, foreach

I want to be able to create the html table like this without using any html and only writing JavaScript.

How do I create the empty table data boxes with JavaScript?

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  }
th {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  }
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>One</th>
      <th>Two</th>
      <th>Three</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>B</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>C</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Are you using bare javascript or a library like jQuery?

Comment: This is incorrect HTML syntax for a `<table>` element. `<th>` tags should only be used as table header cells.

Comment: I've got jQuery and lodash.js

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myTableRows = [
    [{"th":"One"},{"th":"Two"},{"th":"Three"}],
    [{"th":"A"},{"td":""},{"td":""}],
    [{"th":"B"},{"td":""},{"td":""}],
    [{"th":"C"},{"td":""},{"td":""}]
];

var table = document.createElement("table");
for(var rowIndex in myTableRows) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    for(var colIndex in myTableRows[rowIndex]) {
        for(var tag in myTableRows[rowIndex][colIndex]) {
            var cell = document.createElement(tag);
            var cellContents = document.createTextNode(myTableRows[rowIndex][colIndex][tag]);
            cell.appendChild(cellContents);
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
    }
    table.appendChild(row);
}
document.body.appendChild(table);
```